# How to make Formik return a boolean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to get a value back from Formik. It works with a Textfield, but I don't get the value of my switcher back (which is a boolean).

I have my file and switcher setup like this:

```
 <div className="side2">
          <Field
            type="email"
            label={currentEmail}
            name="email"
            placeholder={t('register.email')}
            style={{ width: '55%' }}
            className="fontLogin"
            component={FormikInput}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <div className="side">
          <p>Is admin ?</p>
        </div>
        <div className="side2">
          <Switch
            name="admin"
            id="admin"
            checked={(open === 'true')}
            onChange={() => handleChange(!(open)}
            color="primary"
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox' }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

And in my other file I use formik like this:

```
<Formik
              ref={form}
              initialValues={{ email: '', admin: '' }}
              onSubmit={(values) => {
                handleSubmit(values);
                handleClose();
              }}
              render={(props) => (
                <FormRender
                  t={t}
                  currentEmail={currentEmail}
                  currentAdmin={currentAdmin}
                  currentVerified={currentVerified}
                  activeButton
                  {...props}
                />
              )}
            />
```

I tried to set the value of my switcher to a string with the `.toString()` method, but it doesn't work.

How is it possible to get a switcher value back? What am I misunderstanding here?

Best,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the initial value to `false/true`, then use the `props.values.admin` within the Switch component, and use the [setFieldValue](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void) Formik function to update the value.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{ email: '', admin: false }}
  ...
/>
```

```
<Switch
  ...
  checked={props.values.admin}
  onChange={() => props.setFieldValue("admin", !props.values.admin)}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Hey @dw_, since today i have this error: Cannot read property of undefined. Formik make an update 2 days ago but it dont work anymore ... Any ideas?

Comment: @Kan Are you sure it's not related to some other changes?